# List to Tuples in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to write a clause in Prolog that takes in a list and returns predicates of edges. For example:

```
?- listpairs([1, 2, 3], X, Y).
X = 1
Y = 2;

X = 2
Y = 3;
```

This is what I've tried so far and haven't been getting anywhere.

```
listpairs([H], H, H).
listpairs([H1,H2|T], X, Y) :- 
      X is H1,
      Y is H2,
      listpairs([H2|T], X, Y).
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help.

Comment: Does your base case make sense? Is that what you want? In the recursive case you need to add a disjunction. It should either return values or call recursively, not both.

Comment: *...haven't been getting anywhere*. Not a very good problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by writing:

```
X is H1,
Y is H2
```

X,Y get instantiated which means that their value can't change further so your predicate will fairs since in next iteration of recursion you try to re-instantiate X,Y.

Try:

```
listpairs([H1,H2], H1, H2).
listpairs([H1,H2,_|_], H1, H2).
listpairs([_,H2|T], X, Y) :- listpairs([H2|T], X, Y).
```

Example:

```
?- listpairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], X, Y).
X = 1,
Y = 2 ;
X = 2,
Y = 3 ;
X = 3,
Y = 4 ;
X = 4,
Y = 5 ;
false.
```

Comment: You're welcome, edited the answer before it gave two times the same answer, fixed it, glad to help!!

Comment: Also don't use `is/2` when you're not evaluating arithmetic expression, for assignment just use unification: `=/2`. Note that for example rule: `listpairs([H1,H2,_|_], H1, H2).` could be written equivalently as: `listpairs([H1,H2,_|_], X, Y):- X = X1, Y = H2.`.

Comment: I just ran the edited code and im only getting the first set of predicates (?- listpairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], X, Y).

X = 1
Y = 2
yes;) and not the rest.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to write `;` to get more solutions I just tried it and works fine...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4WNdf im telling you, my dude. must be a weird thing on my end.

Comment: You need to press `;` to get more solutions!! What prolog system do you use?? I just ran it in SWI-Prolog and I ran the exact code in my answer, works perfectly!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161378/discussion-between-user287474-and-coder).